# "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'isrunning' referenced before assignment" Idk why

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

When I Run My Python Program it says

> "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'isrunning' referenced before assignment". I

Don't Know Why This Happens.

I Don't Even Know Where To Start TTo Fix This Problem.

```py
isrunning = True
def redrawgame():
    win.blit(bg, (bgX, 0))  # draws our first bg image
    win.blit(bg, (bgX2, 0))
    if isrunning == True:
        win.blit(Run[imagerun],(x, y))
```

I Define `isrunning` before I use it in `redrawgame()`, so IDK why this is happening. Please Help. I just want this error to go away.

Comment: So you write to the variable `isrunning` somewhere in the function?

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to your question, and show where you're actually calling `redrawgame`. The code won;t be called until you run the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you make an assignment to a variable in a scope, that variable becomes local to that scope.
I assume that you do an assignment to the variable `isrunning` in the scope of `redrawgame`. e.g.:

```py
def redrawgame():

    # [...]  

    isrunning = False
```

Since `isrunning` is local in the scope of `redrawgame`, the statement

> ```
> if isrunning == True:
> ```

tries to read  this local variable, which is not defined at this point. This cases the error:

> "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'isrunning' referenced before assignment".

See also [Why am I getting an UnboundLocalError when the variable has a value?](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value)

To write to a variable in global namespace in the scope of a function you've to use the [`global` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=global#grammar-token-global-stmt):

```py
isrunning = True
def redrawgame():
    global isrunning

    win.blit(bg, (bgX, 0))  # draws our first bg image
    win.blit(bg, (bgX2, 0))
    if isrunning == True:
        win.blit(Run[imagerun],(x, y))

    # [...]

    isrunning = False
```

Now the value is read form the variable in global name space and there is no more local variable with the same name.

Comment: no sorry I didn't know that, I accepted it again. I thought I accept it to mark that it is right.

Answer (score 0):

in `redrawgame()` put global isrunning